# Loop through an array inside a class using foreach

Tags: loop, errors, array, oop

I'm creating a class in my **WordPress template** and I have a multidimensional array as **protected** member. The array at second level contains some *email addresses* as **string** and I want to get those emails through a `foreach` loop. The code is like below.

```
class myclass {
  private $arr = array(
    'emails' => array(
      'someone@example.com',
      'someone@example.com',
      'someone@example.com'
    )
  );
  protected $emails = array();
  foreach($this->arr['emails'] as $email) {
    $this->emails[] .= $email
  }
}
```

---

#### PHP Giving Error

**Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected `for` (`T_FOR`), expecting `function` (`T_FUNCTION`) or `const` (`T_CONST`) in **C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\mytheme\functions.php** on line `no need of this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have code directly in the class definition. If you want it on instantiation, put it in the `__construct` function.

Also, be aware that you were missing a semicolon and `.=` is used to append to strings, not to add to arrays. I've fixed those as well:

```
<?php
class myclass {
  private $arr = array(
    'emails' => array(
      'someone@example.com',
      'someone@example.com',
      'someone@example.com'
    )
  );
  protected $emails = array();

  function __construct() {
    foreach($this->arr['emails'] as $email) {
        $emails[] = $email;
      }
    }
}
```